# Typeset either arbitrary vertical list or a blank space of the same total height, depending on an \if

Tags: spacing, environments

I'm trying to generate two versions of the same document (a classroom handout) from one source: one version with answers printed, another version with blank spaces for the students to write in answers.  I want to have the option of leaving more blank space than the answer takes, or not, but either way, both versions of the document should have the same overall layout.  That is, the gap between one question and the next should always be the same in both versions, the only change should be whether or not the answer is visible in that gap.

The code at the bottom of this question *almost* works.  (I've included all of the documentclass and package settings that seem like they might be relevant.  The important part is the definition of the `solution` environment.)  The only problem is that *sometimes* there is extra space in one or the other version of the document.  I can't figure out where the extra space is coming from.  (The example usage below may or may not show the problem.)  Please advise how to make the vertical space between one question and the next be consistently the same in both versions.  Note that the solution environment may or may not be wrapped in other environments (e.g. an `enumerate` or a `theorem`) and it needs to be consistent regardless.

Advice on how to make the meat of the code not be such a macaronic mash-up of low-level TeX primitives, LaTeX user commands, and calc operations would also be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[
  version=3.11b,
  12pt,
  paper=letter,
  BCOR=0pt,
  headings=small
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{microtype}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=11}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{solutioncolor}{HTML}{6c71c4}

\newif\ifprintanswers
\IfSubStr{\jobname}{\detokenize{-soln}}
  {\printanswerstrue}
  {\printanswersfalse}

\newsavebox{\solnbox}
\newlength{\solnminheight}
\newlength{\solnskip}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{solution}[1][\z@]
  {\setlength{\solnminheight}{#1}
   \setbox\solnbox\vtop\bgroup\color@setgroup\color{solutioncolor}}
  {\color@endgroup\egroup
   \par
   \ifprintanswers
     \setlength{\solnskip}
       {\maxof{\z@}{\solnminheight - (\ht\solnbox + \dp\solnbox)}}%
     \box\solnbox
     \vspace*{\solnskip}%
   \else
     \setlength{\solnskip}
       {\maxof{\solnminheight}{\ht\solnbox + \dp\solnbox}}%
     \vspace*{\solnskip}%
   \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

As with a low sucking sound it slowly disappeared again, Starbuck
still gazing at the agitated waters where it had sunk, with a wild
voice exclaimed---``Almost rather had I seen Moby Dick and fought him,
than to have seen thee, thou white ghost!''

``What was it, Sir?'' said Flask.

\begin{solution}[2ex]
``The great live squid, which, they say, few whale-ships ever beheld,
and returned to their ports to tell of it.''
\end{solution}

But Ahab said nothing; turning his boat, he sailed back to the vessel;
the rest as silently following.

\end{document}
```

Comment: use a box in the second case too. Something like  `\setbox0=\hbox{}\dp0=\dp\solnbox \ht0\ht\solnbox  \box0 `.

Comment: Or `\phantom{\usebox\solnbox}`.